Solving a System of 3 Equations
Let $(a,b,c)$ be the real solution to the system of equations: $$ x^3-xyz=2$$$$y^3-xyz=6$$$$z^3-xyz=20$$ Find the greatest possibe value of $a^3+b^3+c^3$
My approach to the question is: I added all 3 equations and got $(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)=28$
From here it can be said that $(x+y+z)(\frac{2}{x}+\frac{6}{y}+\frac{20}{z})=28$.
How to proceed and get the answer?

We have
$$\begin{align}
&x^3=xyz+2\\
&y^3=xyz+6\\
&z^3=xyz+20
\end{align} $$
Denote $t=xyz$ and take the product of the 3 equations above, we obtain a quadratic equation of $t$:
$$t^3 =(t+2)(t+6)(t+20)\tag{1}$$
The quadratic equation $(1)$ has 2 roots: $t=-4$ and $t=-15/7$.
It’s easy to check that if $xyz=t=-15/7$, we have  a real solution $(x,y,z)=(-1/\sqrt[3]{7},3 /\sqrt[3]{7},5 /\sqrt[3]{7}   )$ and if $xyz=t=-4$, we have a real solution $(x,y,z)=(-\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{2},2 \sqrt[3]{2}   )$
Because $-15/7>-4$, the maximum value of $a^3+b^3+c^3$ is
$$2 +t + 6+t+ 20+t = 28 +3t =\color{red}{ \frac{151}{7}}$$

Yeah Thanks for the help :)

Wait why should there be no real solution for $t=-15/7$? @NN2

Yes i have the same doubt.It is rather maximum at -15/7

@NN2 the real solution corresponding to $xyz=-15/7$ is $(x,y,z): \left(-\frac1{\sqrt[3] 7}, \frac3{\sqrt[3]7}, \frac5{\sqrt[3] 7}\right)$.

@NN2: Maybe I am missing something, but doesn't the other root give a larger sum of $a^3 + b^3+c^3$? The first gives $16$ and the second $21.5714$.

@Sahaj Thanks for pointing the mistake, I corrected it.

Hint.
Eliminating $x,y$ we arrive at
$$
7 z^6-237 z^3+2000=0
$$
and making $u = z^3$ we get $0=7 u^2-237 u+2000=7(u-16)\left(u-\frac{125}7\right)$
etc.
NOTE
As $xy = \frac{z^3-20}{z}$ after substitution we have
$$
\cases{
x^3 = z^3-18\\
y^3 = z^3-14
}\Rightarrow (z^3-20)^3 = z^3(z^3-18)(z^3-14)
$$
arriving to
$$
(7z^3-125)(z^3-16) = 0
$$

Please. See note included.
